Медиаплеер на C# с нуля
Всем привет, хочу сделать свой медиа плеер на C#, понимаю, что неактуально, но есть пару идей, которые можно реализовать, так как нигде такого не видел. Хочется узнать где лучше делать его и какие библиотеки использовать. Видел способ через Visual Studio WF, но интересно было бы посмотреть какие еще есть способы, среды для создания подобного. Даже если и делать через windows forms, то вопрос следующий, можно ли как то в коде залезть и реализовать настройки видео, как это реализовано в обычном плеере винды (скрин ниже). Сколько смотрел примеров, не наблюдал, чтобы кто-то вообще делал их в собственном проекте, а мне они нужны для создания определенных функций. Также мне нужно как то добраться до аудиодорожек видео (многие видео разделены на 2 и более аудиодорожки и необходимо реализовать переключение между ними соответственно). Заранее спасибо за ответ, хотя бы на один вопрос

Берете нужный для вас тип проекта (если Windows, то WPF или WinUI, ну а если кросплатформ, то MAUI, для сайтов ASP), далее ищите библиотеку, которая будет воспроизводить вам медиа контент (вы ведь не хотите сами каждый формат реализовывать, разбираться в кодеках, и так далее, верно? К примеру, можно взять VLC. Долго "курите" документацию библиотеки, ну и реализуете поверх свои хотелки. Готово. Помню делал просмотр торрента на WPF, вот что-то подобное вам и надо)

Напрямую работать с кодеком можно.

На самом деле идея не плохая, т.к. на wpf нет вообще ни одного нативного проигрывателя

@evo плохих идей не бывает, бывают плохие реализации. Но соглашусь, что в тех же MAUI/WinAppSDK ситуация с медиаплеером сильно лучше.

https://habr.com/ru/articles/717726/

Есть ffmpeg шарповый: [https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen] (https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen) Но лучше и не начинай.
